# Bar chart in pandas on time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do bar chart in pandas on time series data.

Documentation says it is not possible: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots

Is there some workaround ?

This is my code

```
# there must be ORDER BY, other wise rows will not be ordered
df = sql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM hzmo_report ORDER BY datum;", cnx, index_col='datum') 

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) # converting to DatetimeIndex 

df['korisnika'].plot(ax=axs1[0], title='SOMETHING', marker='o')
df['korisnika'].diff().plot(ax=axs1[1], title='SOMETHING', marker='o') # i would like this to be bar plot
```

If I do

```
df['korisnika'].diff().plot(kind='bar', ax=axs1[1], title='SOMETHING', marker='o')
```

I have just added kind='bar'

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-d41eb2b2e3a7> in <module>()
     36 fig1.suptitle('Umirovljenici', fontsize=16)
     37 df['korisnika'].plot(ax=axs1[0], title='Broj korisnika mirovine', marker='o')
---> 38 ( df['korisnika'].diff() ).plot(ax=axs1[1], kind='bar', title='Apsolutna razlika naspram prethodnog mjeseca', marker='o')
     39 #df['korisnika'].diff().hist()
     40 

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in plot_series(series, label, kind, use_index, rot, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, ax, style, grid, legend, logy, secondary_y, **kwds)
   1504                      secondary_y=secondary_y, **kwds)
   1505 
-> 1506     plot_obj.generate()
   1507     plot_obj.draw()
   1508 

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in generate(self)
    731         self._compute_plot_data()
    732         self._setup_subplots()
--> 733         self._make_plot()
    734         self._post_plot_logic()
    735         self._adorn_subplots()

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _make_plot(self)
   1291             else:
   1292                 rect = bar_f(ax, self.ax_pos + i * 0.75 / K, y, 0.75 / K,
-> 1293                              start=pos_prior, label=label, **kwds)
   1294             rects.append(rect)
   1295             labels.append(label)

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in f(ax, x, y, w, start, **kwds)
   1251         if self.kind == 'bar':
   1252             def f(ax, x, y, w, start=None, **kwds):
-> 1253                 return ax.bar(x, y, w, bottom=start, **kwds)
   1254         elif self.kind == 'barh':
   1255             def f(ax, x, y, w, start=None, **kwds):

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
   4779                 label='_nolegend_'
   4780                 )
-> 4781             r.update(kwargs)
   4782             r.get_path()._interpolation_steps = 100
   4783             #print r.get_label(), label, 'label' in kwargs

C:\Documents and Settings\hr1ub098\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in update(self, props)
    657             func = getattr(self, 'set_'+k, None)
    658             if func is None or not callable(func):
--> 659                 raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s'%k)
    660             func(v)
    661             changed = True

AttributeError: Unknown property marker
```

Comment: Why would you not believe the documentation?

Comment: It is not that I do not believe documentation. My question is how to do it, because kind='bar' will not do.

Comment: Time series are continuous in time, histograms are discrete bins.  Maybe you just need to define bins, figure out what value to assign (average?), and then "bar" that.

Answer (score 3):

You can plot a bar-plot of a time-series. Not that useful IMHO though.

```
ts = Series(randn(20),date_range('20130101',periods=20))
ts.plot()
```

A time-series line-plot

[image]

A Bar Plot

[image]

Comment: Your example is working. I have updated my code example. As far as I can see it is not working only in line that I gave as example. In this my code it is working fine:  df['korisnika'].diff().plot(kind='bar', title='Verizni indeksi')  I need bar plot, because I am using it on diff() so bar plot gives better visualizations on changes from previous period.